# mysql order by last value in table separated by comma

Tags: php, mysql

so I'll try to be short, 
I'm trying to ORDER BY ID from table whose values are separated by commas. 
Here's an Image:

[image]

---

I want them to be ordered like this when displayed: 34, 40, 33, 0.

here's my code:

```
            /// movie
            $myuserid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $mymovies = "SELECT p_movies FROM user_details WHERE user_id='$myuserid' ";
            $mymoviesresult = mysqli_query($_db,$mymovies);
            $mymovie = mysqli_fetch_array($mymoviesresult); 
            /// movie

            $mypurchases = $mymovie['p_movies'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE find_in_set(id, '$mypurchases') > 0";
            $res_data = mysqli_query($_db,$sql);
                if($res_data = mysqli_query($_db, $sql)){
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($res_data) > 0){
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){ include 'movies/appearance.php'; }}}
```

I tried to add **ORDER BY DESC** and **ASC**, it doesn't work. Is it possible to order results in the manner stated above? 
Don't know how to explain it better, sorry for my English.

Comment: You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: *I want them to be ordered like this when displayed: 34, 40, 33, 0.* What determines exactly this sorting order?

Comment: @Akina It appears to be the reverse order of `p_movies`.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe... but I'd like OP to tell this...

Comment: @Akina Yes, i want it to be reversed order of p_movies as Barmar said and those numbers could've been words, for example - a,c,e,b,o and i would want them to be displayed - o,b,e,c,a in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `FIND_IN_SET()` returns the position in the list, you can use that for your ordering.

There's also no need to use two queries, you can join the tables. And you should use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

```
$stmt = $_db->prepare("
    SELECT m.*
    FROM movies AS m
    JOIN user_details AS d ON FIND_IN_SET(m.id, d.p_movies)
    WHERE d.user_id = ?
    ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(m.id, d.p_movies) DESC") or die($_db->error);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['user_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        include 'movies/appearance.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I'm a beginner in php language, started it as hobby. Haven't really used table joining.  I'm getting **Fatal error
: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in** And is d.user_id = ? supposed to be with a question mark?

Comment: I updated the answer to add error checking. What does the full error message say?

Comment: Of course it's supposed to be a question mark. Have you read any of the documentation on prepared statements? The question mark is replaced with the value of the variable in `bind_param`.

Comment: The error **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE d.user_id = ?' at line 5** Oh, I haven't really read, thank you. I guess I should....

Comment: Never mind, I was stupid, I had `WHERE` in the wrong place.